# File 'C:\xampp\tmp\php3226.tmp' could not be renamed. It already exists error in zend, how to?

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-upload

i am using this function to upload files to the disk:

```
$talentFolderPath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project/';

public function uploadToDisk($talentFolderPath, $filename)
{

    $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $adapter->setDestination($talentFolderPath);
    $adapter->addFilter( 'Rename',array('target' => $talentFolderPath."/".$filename) );
    if ($adapter->receive()) {
        $message = "success";
    } else {
        $message = "fail";
    }

    return $message;
}
```

and i get this message:

> Message: File 'C:\xampp\tmp\php3226.tmp' could not be renamed. It already exists.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Rename` filter will not overwrite the target file by default if it already exists which appears to be what you are experiencing.

This snippet is out of `Zend/Filter/File/Rename.php`

```
    if (file_exists($file['target'])) {
        require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Filter_Exception(sprintf("File '%s' could not be renamed. It already exists.", $value));
    }
```

To get around this, you must pass the `overwrite` option like this:

```
$adapter->addFilter('Rename', array(
    'target'    => $talentFolderPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename,
    'overwrite' => true
));
```

See [Zend_Filter_File_Rename](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.rename) for more details.

Comment: thanks for taking interest in this question, i was loosing hope :), that `overwrite` worked. cool

Comment: You're welcome.  The error is a little misleading since it says the name of the temp file and then "It already exists".  Saying, "The rename target already exists" or "The destination file already exists" would be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks dude, it fixed my exact issue also, and now it is working fine :) .